# Pimcore Custom Button Link on Toolbar CKEditor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, pimcore

[Toolbars CKEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U54tl.png)

The result by filling up the data like picture above is

```
<a id="detil" name="detil" </a>
```

What I want to ask is how should I do to have a result

```
<a data-target="#modal-detil" data-toggle="modal" href="#detil"  id="detil" name="detil" </a>
```

How to add the attributes: data target, data toggle and href ?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery add attribute :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#detil").attr("href","#detil");
$("#detil").attr("data-toggle","modal");
$("#detil").attr("data-target","#modal-detil");
});
```

Comment: Hai Sarika, thankyou for the answer,

Did you check image above?? So I want to create attributes data target, data toggle and href automatically when click button link on toolbars CKEditor and select anchor.

I hope you understand what I mean. Thankyou